# docx4j - replacing a bookmark with text and style

Tags: java, google-docs, docx, docx4j

I have a similar problem as [XPages - docx4j - replacing a bookmark with text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24998463/xpages-docx4j-replacing-a-bookmark-with-text) but I would like to keep the style.
My bookmark is not on a text (because it's a docx created by Google Docs), I'd like to keep the text after my bookmark to include it in the bookmark and keep its style.
For example :

```
<w:bookmarkStart w:colFirst="0" w:colLast="0" w:name="3znysh7" w:id="2"/><w:bookmarkEnd w:id="2"/>
<w:r w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000">
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Calibri" w:cs="Calibri" w:eastAsia="Calibri" w:hAnsi="Calibri"/>
        <w:i w:val="1"/>
        <w:color w:val="1e4d78"/>
        <w:rtl w:val="0"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t xml:space="preserve">MY_BOOKMARK</w:t>
</w:r>
```

I found a solution to erase the text after the bookmark, I found a solution to add the text inside the bookmark, but I'm unable to keep the style.

I'm not native English speaker, so do not hesitate to ask me if I'm not clear.

Comment: This looks more like VariableReplace.  Can you change MY_BOOKMARK to the formatting expected ie ${MY_BOOKMARK}

Comment: I'm not sure to understand about VariableReplace. I cannot change MY_BOOKMARK because I cannot manage the source documents

Comment: You'll need to look at the VariableReplace code and modify it to suit your case (since you can't modify the source code).  Or pre-process the document to put your variables in the correct format.  But if you are going to traverse to do that, you may as well just replace the variable with your value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I create a new R and insert it between bookmarkStart and bookmarkEnd.
I had another problem with this kind of example :

```
<w:bookmarkStart w:colFirst="0" w:colLast="0" w:name="30j0zll" w:id="1" />
      <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="1" />
      <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidP="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000">
         <w:pPr>
            <w:pBdr />
            <w:tabs>
               <w:tab w:val="left" w:pos="1560" />
            </w:tabs>
            <w:spacing w:after="0" w:lineRule="auto" />
            <w:contextualSpacing w:val="0" />
            <w:rPr>
               <w:color w:val="2f5496" />
               <w:sz w:val="28" />
               <w:szCs w:val="28" />
            </w:rPr>
         </w:pPr>
         <w:r w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000">
            <w:rPr>
               <w:color w:val="2f5496" />
               <w:sz w:val="20" />
               <w:szCs w:val="20" />
               <w:rtl w:val="0" />
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t xml:space="preserve">MY_BOOKMARK1.</w:t>
         </w:r>
         <w:bookmarkStart w:colFirst="0" w:colLast="0" w:name="1fob9te" w:id="2" />
         <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="2" />
         <w:r w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000">
            <w:rPr>
               <w:color w:val="2f5496" />
               <w:sz w:val="20" />
               <w:szCs w:val="20" />
               <w:rtl w:val="0" />
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t xml:space="preserve">MY_BOOKMARK2</w:t>
         </w:r>
         <w:r w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000">
            <w:rPr>
               <w:rtl w:val="0" />
            </w:rPr>
         </w:r>
      </w:p>
```

My solution :

1. Keep the bookmark with the name 0j0zll
2. Create a new bookmark (id is number of bookmark in the xml file ; id++) and insert it

Hope that could help others